# PHP parse Ajax-request sent from Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on a real-time timetable for a scool. Now when i'm testing it i'm getting an Error **only in internet explorer**. I use ie v.11 and charset UTF-8

When i send the data of the current student to a php-script there are some characters like ä,ö,ü which get parse to a ?. But only in InternetExplorer.

if i sent a URL like this: `http://adopraesenz.ipwin.ch/data/students.php?q=getWirth Nalia;3:Kürzel;0;0;4;0;0;0;`

and want to receive them in the php like this

```
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
echo $q;
```

i get this output: `getWirth Nalia;3:K?rzel;0;0;4;0;0;0;`

I'm sending data like this:

```
function getData(str) {
            var requestURL = "http://adopraesenz.ipwin.ch/data/students.php?q=" +str;
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {           
                if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
                    loadJson(request);
                }
            };
            request.open("GET", requestURL, true);
            request.send();
        }
```

for more code or information please ask.

Comment: did you try utf without bom ?

Comment: do you mean BOM? yes i use utf-8 without bom but also tried utf-8-bom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you should always use `urlencode` and `urldecode` if you want to send data over a GET request. First encode your parameters, and after receiving decode them again. Most webservers will do the decoding for you, so you only have to call the encode code most of the time.
Also check that your form is using the same charset in html and http-header (utf-8 prefered)

Examples from [official php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php)

**encode**

```
<?php
echo '<a href="mycgi?foo=', urlencode($userinput), '">';
```

**decode** (webserver will do this for you most of the time)

```
<?php
$query = "my=apples&are=green+and+red";

foreach (explode('&', $query) as $chunk) {
    $param = explode("=", $chunk);

    if ($param) {
        printf("Value for parameter \"%s\" is \"%s\"<br/>\n", urldecode($param[0]), urldecode($param[1]));
    }
}
```

An easier solution would be to use a post request instead of get, this is the prefered way for sending json data.

Comment: I think this depends on the webserver, but most of them do, you are right. Decode is not necessary most of the time. I will edit my answer. And variables like $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] will not be decoded! You have to do this on your own.